# Selenium __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text_'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I solve this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



try:
    description=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,'./html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/text()')))
finally:
    driver.quit()

print(description)
```

Error:
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text_'

I tried to add text but I can't find a way how to do it

Thank you all for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Python wait for text to be present in element error shows takes 3 arguments 2 given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238574/selenium-python-wait-for-text-to-be-present-in-element-error-shows-takes-3-argum)

Comment: You haven't included the text you want to be present in your `text_to_be_present_in_element()` after providing the element to look for the text in

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think there is a violation of the `text_to_be_present_in_element()` method notation.

Means you have to add the text you want to search for into the method parameters, but pay attention on the brackets at this point, method then will return a bool if text is in:

Yours:

```py
description=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element
((By.XPATH,'./html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/text()')
<-Missing text->))
```

Should work:

```py
description = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,
'./html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/text()'),
 "Input the Text you are searching for or an equivalent String"))
```